# How is this a First Post?

Tags: discussion, review

I got this [First Post review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/3833899).

The [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454252) who, presumably, has posted it isn't a new one based on the rep and profile. Although the post doesn't look like an answer.

So how has this landed in my First Post review?

I'm guessing it's either an audit or a bug. More inclined towards the former.

Will get to know after I complete the review. Even if it was an audit, isn't it poorly designed?

Comment: "Review audit passed 1 min ago"

Comment: Yes it was an audit!

Comment: By the time I posted this question the audit was passed on to someone else. Nonetheless I was given the audit passed message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Even if it was an audit, isn't it poorly designed?

It was, and no, because you’re paying attention. =)

Comment: And if you aren't, [minitech is watching you](http://olive-drab.com/gallery/photos/heswatchingyou_poster_sm.jpg).